# Sending variable with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm having some troubles trying to send an id through ajax script,
I'm trying to create an address book, when you select a contact it load all his information in another page and the ajax script load this page inside the main. Everything is working except to send the ID of the contact. There's a bit of the code :

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "select.php",
         dataType: "html",
         data: {id: id},
         success: function(Result) {
         $('#result').html(Result);
         }
        });
```

PHP

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ca11 WHERE contact_id= $id";
```

does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: add `type: POST`

Comment: you haven't provided the type of request in the ajax if its post

Comment: be careful with the query though, don't directly inject variables into query statements, prepare them instead

Comment: learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) and do what @Akintunde said to do.

Comment: Oh it's working with the type: post thx !

Comment: you're not providing the type, you also have a space character between contact_id= $id; you should also think about using a prepared sql query to avoid some security issues. Finally, make sure your contact_id field is defined as an integer and not a varchar in your database

Answer (score 1):

you need to add which type of request you are making, as your question, you can call post request as below

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "select.php",
  dataType: "html",
  data: {id: id},
  success: function(Result) {
         $('#result').html(Result);
     }
});
```

For more information you can refer this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/